# Related to JavaScript Classes

Tags: javascript, html, class, web

I am new to JS.

I want to know if I can destroy or delete a JS class instance during runtime.

For example, its the code :

```
class Car {
  // code
}

let c = new Car();

//now I want to delete or destroy the class instance c
```

What can I do now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a delete operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: @Leo — … which has no effect on variables, only on properties.

Comment: Also, javascript has a GC: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign a different value to `c`, or let the function which defines it finish without creating any closures that reference `c`.

```
c = null;
```

When no references to an object remain it will be eligible for JS' [garbage collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection) process.

Comment: Means it can not be deleted, only can be set to a different value

Comment: @HarshS. — You can't delete a *variable*, but you didn't ask that. You asked how to delete the instance of Car that was assigned to it.